# Unable to use actor - or find documentation - in gazebo 2

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I'm trying to model a human in gazebo, initially I tried using urdf but having to many problems. I'm now considering to try and model directly in gazebo - using sdf!?! - and I though the best place to start is to see what the actor element or model can do, especially as I'd like to have a smooth single mesh affected by multiple links - as what I believe actor dose - not by chopping the mesh into rigid parts as I'm doing at the moment

I can't find the tutorials that was on http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/intermediate/animated_characters, one day I was able to access it in the morning and then in the evening the wiki shape changed and no longer offer to search for similar pages. I also searched for the dae files and included this code in a world file

```
    <actor name="actor1" static="true">
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <skin>
          <filename> /home/muhammad/gazebo_models/walk.dae </filename>
        </skin>
    </actor>
```

However I get the following error

```
    Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [filename]
gzserver: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:653: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = sdf::Element; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = sdf::Element*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 25074, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver /home/muhammad/catkin_ws/src/inmoov_gazebo/worlds/inmoov.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/muhammad/.ros/log/150be0e0-bc35-11e4-b963-0004769f65c7/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/muhammad/.ros/log/150be0e0-bc35-11e4-b963-0004769f65c7/gazebo-2*.log
```

Can anyone direct me to where to find the code and tutorials for animating characters please?!? I'd also appreciate any recommendations regarding simulating humans, I will need to attempt to lift the human using a robot so I plane to include inertia and kinematic parameters

Thanks in advance, and I apologise if the question is not very clear, this is my first question here

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8066/unable-to-use-actor---or-find-documentation---in-gazebo-2/) by [Muhammad Badr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1119/muhammad-badr/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There were some problems with the Actor code that was fixed in Gazebo5. Could you try using [Gazebo5](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install)?

Take a look at the [example](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/worlds/actor.world), and make sure the the files your references are in your `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Muhammad Badr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1119/muhammad-badr/) on 2015-02-24**:
thanks, however I'm not very experienced with gazebo and want to use it with ros indigo, I'm not sure I'll be able to use it with gazebo 5

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2015-02-25**:
Here is information about using (gazebo5 with Indigo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros#Gazebo5.xseries)

**Comment by [Muhammad Badr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1119/muhammad-badr/) on 2015-02-26**:
thanks, any idea what happened to the tutorial or where to find it?!? it had something about making new meshes for the actors using blender and models from makehuman

**Comment by [Muhammad Badr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1119/muhammad-badr/) on 2015-02-26**:
Unfortunately I keep having other problems after installing gazebo5 - such as the pioneer robot rolling over instead of moving forward as it should and as in gazebo2 -  any suggestions on how to fix the actor code in gazebo2?!?